# Single pixel, Horizontal white flickering line, when bright window is near

Tags: display, hdmi, displayport

So I just got a brand new monitor.
When using DisplayPort I get a single white line on the side of the monitor, but only when a bright window is near it. The monitor is connected via a docking station.

**Facts:**

1. It is not there when i screenshot the area.
2. It is present on multiple laptops, across multiple cables.
3. This only happens on DisplayPort and not when using HDMI.
4. It is the same across multiple resolutions as well.
5. The line is only present when a window with bright colors are near the area.
6. The line has the same height as whatever bright window is near.

What are the chances that this is a faulty panel vs its the dockingstation that needs changing?
I have no other dockingstation to test, sadly.